# (Win 7+VS 2013) Should WDK 8.1 Update be sufficient by itself for installing build environments?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, wdk

I have Visual Studio 2013 running on Windows 7 Pro. I needed the Windows Driver Kit for a project so I downloaded and installed this [WDK 8.1 Update (for Windows 8.1, 8, and 7 drivers)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg454513.aspx).

In this case I had not installed components such as [the Windows Driver Kit Version 7.1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800) before installing WDK 8.1 Update.

Now I do not see the build environments created anywhere so I am not sure if this version of WDK requires either an earlier version of WDK as well, if something went wrong during installation, or if Microsoft made changes to the build environments.

However, when I had the aforementioned Windows Driver Kit Version 7.1.0 installed on another machine, it had created the build environments shown below.

[image: WDK Build Environments in Windows Start Menu]

Should the WDK 8.1 Update be sufficient on its own to create the build environments and if so, where can they be accessed?

Comment: The olden makefile based driver development approach was retired.  In VS2013 use File > New > Project > Visual C++ > Windows Driver to find templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Window 8 all tools (Debugger, Windows performance Tools, ADK, WDK) are installed under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\VERSION` and can be found under `Windows Kits` in the startmenu. Look a bit under your current position to access the `Windows Kits` folder.